# Why are Deathclaws attacking my vault so much?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My vault seemed to be doing okay, I guess. I mean, I’m questing 24/7 and that gives me tons of stuff! That’s good, right? But then I got some Deathclaws and I thought: “Well, it’ll pass. My dwellers are really strong. They’ll make it.” And sure enough, they literally died on the first floor. After I finished another quest, and my people got in just in time, more Deathclaws attacked.

Now I get, like, four attacks per day and my dwellers keep complaining about not feeling well and I’ve spent about 86,000 caps on reviving people and my two Mr. Handy’s. Is there a specific reason, or amount of dwellers that causes your attacks to spike?

Answer (score 5):

Deathclaws are (clearly) the most deadly version of the raiding monsters that will attack your Vault. They are fast, and incredibly strong, so the best mechanic is to increase your Dwellers' Armour and HP to survive the encounter, as Deathclaws will move through the Vault quickly, regardless of whether or not they kill all the Dwellers in a room. If you focus on keeping your dwellers alive, the damage dealt by everyone will eventually be enough to kill them. Once you have a team strong enough to withstand the attack, you can then focus on upping your damage.

As for what causes Deathclaws to attack, the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_(Fallout_Shelter)) hs this to say (emphasis mine):

> - According to in-game information, Deathclaws **are more likely to attack the vault if the vault doors are opened**, immediately after sending dwellers to the wasteland or on quests and if there is a radio station broadcasting out to the wasteland.[3]
> - Deathclaws will begin to attack when the vault has **60+ dwellers**. They will start attacking at **35+ dwellers when playing in Survival mode**.

So, if you are still having issues with Deathclaw attacks

1. Reduce the number of Dwellers in your Vault. If you drop the Number of Dwellers below 60 (35 in Survival) the Deathclaw attacks will stop.
2. Increase the Dweller's Armour, and HP, then Damage.

Comment: Armor, AFAIK, actually does nothing other than boost your stats.  I can't observe any differences between an unarmored dweller and one in X01 Power Armor.  The dwellers are controlled by having 15 END at level 1 until they are level 50, so they have the same max HP.

Answer (score 2):

If too many deathclaws are attacking your vault, then you must get rid of vault dwellers.
In regular, after 60 dwellers are reached, they start attacking, and I believe in survival it is 35. And, as said above, when the doors open.